# How to resize an icon in ToolbarAndroid with React Native?

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native

In React Native we have the *ToolbarAndroid* with **actions** property and **logo**

Actions takes an array of objects, where each object can have the icon key.

Example:

```
<ToolbarAndroid
  logo={require('./app_logo.png')}
  title="AwesomeApp"
  actions={[{title: 'Settings', icon: require('./icon_settings.png'), show: 'always'}]} />
```

How can I resize icon and logo? Can I change the icon color?

Comment: No, currently its not supported.